# Significant Change Notifications Live On Beyond Shutdown, Even Version Upgrades?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have an app that uses LocationManager. For a while I was using Significant Location Change notifications. As I read the documentation, I believed 2 things to be true:

1. They did not really consume any extra battery because you were basically telling the phone, 'just give me knowledge you already have.'
2. When the app was off, the notifications stopped.

Once I introduced that, I got a lot of emails from people accusing me of burning up their battery. So I took it out.

Got an email yesterday from a fellow showing me that the location arrow in Settings/Privacy was still purple, even when the app wasn't running. That's also true on my phone.

I can only think of two possibilities:

1. The registration for significant change notifications is still in tact, despite upgrades to newer versions, etc.
2. Or, one time the app crashed while the location manager was on and it was never turned off.

2 seems pretty far fetched, as I would think there would be a ton of that happening potentially. I was kind of disappointed that there's no way in Instruments to see what the system believes its obligations to the app are, and when they have been in effect since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to see what delegates are active for an app, even beyond the app running actively.

From what I know about the significantLocationChanges, they work along the same principles as the regionMonitoring. If you have users complaining about battery life, they are likely getting burned by something else. -significantLocationChanges uses fewer items for location than -regionMonitoring does. I believe they are strictly cell-tower related. They may use Wifi detection as well, but they don't advertise it.

Also, the location monitoring will persist even when the app has been killed and between updates and upgrades. I don't know how the app will behave if you upgrade the app and remove the delegate methods while the app is still monitoring for them. My guess is they will get orphaned out there, the callbacks would try to notify your app but the methods are gone and will be ignored. Just a guess, but might be worth testing out. It might be worth leaving those in or a method that will remove all location monitoring. Then remove all that in a later update just to make sure nobody still has any active location code out there.

Comment: THat's the conclusion I had come to: put out a release that explicitly calls for stopping the significant change notifications. Then maybe go back to that as the technique, but have it suspend the notifications whenever the app goes into the background; I really don't need to keep getting updates when the user is not using my app.

Comment: Good plan. If you don't need the callbacks, you should tear down the CLLocationManagerDelegate so none of that is being handled in the background. Keeps battery life up, and doesn't show that your app is using location when it really isn't.

Comment: The delegates are all being torn down now for sure, but I was understanding the docs and your note to agree with the claim I made that the request for SLCs must survive not only shutdowns, but version upgrades as well. Hence, if you are going to use them and don't want to literally turn the indicator on for the rest of eternity, better call stop at some point.